# how are these simultaneous equations derived from stated equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I am reading, in my free time, "Fundamentals of Physics" by Walker | Haliday | Resnick; Tenth edition.

I am reading chapter 9 section 9-7: "Elastic Collisions in one Dimension"

We start off with these equations:

$m_1v_{1_i} = m_1v_{1_f} + m_2v_{2_f}$ (linear momentum)       (9-63)

$m_1v_{1_i}^2 = 1/2m_1v_{1_f}^2 + 1/2m_2v_{2_f}^2$ (kinetic energy)  (9-64)

"To do so, we rewrite Eq. 9-63 as

$m_1(v_{1_i} - v_{1_f}) = m_2v_{2_f}$    (9-65)

"and Eq. 964 as

$m_1(v_{1_i} - v_{1_f})(v_{1_i} + v_{1_f}) = m_2v_{2_f}^2$      (9-66)

"After dividing Eq.9-66 by Eq.9-65 and doing some more algebra, we obtain

$v_{1_f} = \frac{m_1 - m_2}{m_1 + m_2}v_{1_i}$     (9-67)

and

$v_{2_f} = \frac{2m_1}{m_1 + m_2}v_{1_i}$      (9-68)

---

Now my question is, what does "dividing Eq.9-66 by Eq.9-65 and doing some more algebra" exactly mean here?

I don't know how they 'divided' those equations to get those simultaneous equations.

I've tried to set Eq.9-66 in terms of ${v_{1_f}}$ by re-arranging Eq.9-65 but I still don't end up with anything remotely what they have.  Almost always I end up with too little $m_1$ or $m_2$'s.

I am not sure what math I am missing here to be able to do what they summed up as a division and "some more algebra".  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

NOTE: This is not homework, I'm just reading a physics book because I want to learn physics.  :) I haven't been in school since 2004.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say they divide 9-66 by 9-65, they're saying that you divide the left-hand side (LHS) of 9-66 by the LHS of 9-65, and the RHS of 9-66 by the RHS of 9-65:

$$ \frac{m_1\left(v_{1_i} - v_{1_f}\right)\left(v_{1_i} + v_{1_f}\right)}{m_1\left(v_{1_i} - v_{1_f}\right)} = \frac{m_2v_{2_f}^2}{m_2v_{2_f}} $$

$$ \Rightarrow v_{1_i} + v_{1_f} = v_{2_f} .$$

The "some more algebra" is just substituting $v_{1_i}+v_{1_f}$ for $v_{2_f}$ into 9-65:

$$ m_1\left(v_{1_i} - v_{1_f}\right) = m_2v_{2_f} $$
$$ \Rightarrow m_1\left(v_{1_i} - v_{1_f}\right) = m_2\left(v_{1_i} + v_{1_f}\right) $$
$$ \Rightarrow v_{1_f} = \frac{(m_1 - m_2)}{(m_1 + m_2)} v_{1_i} .$$

And substituting $v_{2_f}$ for $v_{1_i}+v_{1_f}$ into 9-66 (with an assist from 9-67 to eliminate $v_{1_f}$):

$$ m_1\left(v_{1_i}-v_{1_f}\right)\left(v_{2_f} + v_{1_f}\right) = m_2v_{2_f}^2 $$
$$ \Rightarrow m_1\left(v_{1_i}-v_{1_f}\right)v_{2_f} = m_2v_{2_f}^2 $$
$$ \Rightarrow m_1\left(v_{1_i}-\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{1_i}\right) = m_2v_{2_f} $$
$$ \Rightarrow m_1\left(1-\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}\right)v_{1_i} = m_2v_{2_f} $$
$$ \Rightarrow m_1\left(\frac{m_1+m_2}{m_1+m_2}-\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}\right)v_{1_i} = m_2v_{2_f} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{2m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}v_{1_i} = m_2v_{2_f} $$
$$ \Rightarrow v_{2_f} = \frac{2m_1}{m_1+m_2}v_{1_i} .$$

Comment: +1 for answering.  I just wondered what happens to the $v_{1_i} - $ (on the RHS) in the second to last line.  I don't see how it goes away in the last line?

Comment: Added a couple more lines in there, factor out the $v_{1_i}$ and combine what's left inside the parentheses.